# How to create custom map with Geo Position

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, google-maps, geolocation

I want to create an app for ipad with custom map (very small pice of global map, like a google map), which have my design, but with same geo attributes as google map (for example). Can you advise me something?

Comment: Too generic a question. Take a look at the "iOS MapKit" documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be useful to take a look at **Google Maps - Overlays**